# In my native language, we have this proverb: when an ox cart is turned over (or turns over) only then one will see the road

Tags: idiom-requests

The implication is that when something bad happens, only then one will see the results. Is there a semantically identical idiom in English? Can this idiom be considered as an equivalent to the above-mentioned one ? - Shut the stable door after the horse has bolted ?

Comment: That's a great idiom!  Out of curiosity, which language does that come from?

Comment: The Georgian language.

Comment: We call that a *wake-up call*.

Comment: All I can think of as close to, but not exactly the same, would be "You reap what you sow."

Comment: The road isn't a result of the accident. Are you saying that seeing the road is obvious evidence that there has been an accident? I can't see why you'd need such confirmation.

Comment: Your 'fire' example is certainly the equivalent of 'shutting the stable door after the horse has bolted'. Like Edwin, I find the 'cart' expression more difficult to understand.

Comment: Is there an element of "seize an opportunity to take first place/lead the way when the previous leader fails" Is the point the bad thing that happened or the opportunity to the next person?

Comment: Let`s say, you`re looking at the cart from behind, which is moving in front of you. It blocks your view so you can`t see the road. But as soon as it turns over, you`ll see the road again immediately. This proverb has a figurative meaning, we tend to use it when we want to emphasize a fact that, one is going to face the consequences of an incident, only after it`s happened. Only after the house had been completely burnt down, the new settlers realized how important it was to install an anti-fire system. They realized it only after the house was burnt down.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The closest thing that I can think of would be the fairly common expression in English [**hindsight is 20/20**](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/hindsight_is_20/20):

> In hindsight, things that are obvious now were not obvious from the outset; one is able to evaluate past choices more clearly than at the time of the choice.

Quite obviously, it's not the exact equivalent, but conceptually the two expressions are really more or less the same. To get a better idea how this idiom works, take a look at this example:

> With 20/20 hindsight, it's now obvious that we should not have trusted this charlatan from the very beginning! He cheated us out of all our money!

Comment: It still doesn't convey the good event vs bad event aspect

Comment: Well, it certainly can convey that idea. It all just depends on how you use it.

Comment: Given Gio's example of "Only after the house had been completely burnt down, the new settlers realized how important it was to install an anti-fire system. They realized it only after the house was burnt down." there is no better answer in English than "hindsight is 20/20".

Answer (score 2):

**a rude awakening** [TFD](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/awaken)

> The shocking instance of learning the unpleasant or unwelcome truth
>   about a situation.

Answer (score 1):

You don't know what you have until you've lost it.

> Don't know what you got till it's gone
>  Don't know what it is I did
>   so wrong
>  [Cinderella lyrics](https://www.azlyrics.com/lyrics/cinderella/dontknowwhatyougottillitsgone.html)

Answer (score 1):

It appears that the proverb warns one to not wait until an unfortunate incident to see the results helplessly (the "harsh" reality of the "road" after the cart has overturned) but be prepared to prevent it (make sure the cart is moving smoothly by "driving" it gently, maintaining it in a good state of repair, etc). In that sense, a good English counterpart may be "***Foresight is better than hindsight***".

TFD(idioms):

> **[Foresight is better than hindsight](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/Foresight+is+better+than+hindsight)**.
>   *cliché* It is better to anticipate and prevent future problems than to realize how they could have been avoided after the fact.
>   If I
>   were you, I would pay the extra $50 for full insurance coverage while
>   you're traveling. You never know what might happen, and foresight is
>   better than hindsight.
>
> Farlex Dictionary of Idioms. © 2015 Farlex, Inc, all rights reserved.

Answer (score 0):

"[Every cloud has a silver lining](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/every+cloud+has+a+silver+lining)"

The Free Dictionary says:

> It is possible for something good to come out of a bad situation. (A
>   silver lining on a cloud is an indication that the sun is behind it.)

Answer (score 0):

Consider the following quote:

> Good decisions come from experience, and experience comes from bad decisions
>   [- attributed to Mark Twain at AZ Quotes](http://www.azquotes.com/quote/610491)

The experience resulting from bad decisions parallels your idiom's *overturned cart*, and the experience leading to good decisions parallels your idiom's *road*.