# Touching leaves after burning your hands

Tags: idioms, idiom-requests

I  would  like  to  know  an equal idiom in English  for  an  Idiom 
in  Telugu

> **it  is like touching  leaves  after  burning  your hands** 
>    meaning  doing something  to  rectify  the  situation after  the total damage  has  been done.

It  is not crying  over split milk

It  is  not  a  duplicate  .My  mother tongue  is  not  Flemish..I  asked  the  question  because  the  idiom  is  there  in  my  mothertongue  for which  I  did  not  know  the  English  Idiom.When I  asked the  question I did  not  have  the  slightest  possibility  to  see the  previous  post.It  is  rather  coincidental that  the  idiom  has  almost  the  same  meaning  has  mine.

Here  is  a  link  which  differes  in  meaning  to  the  idiom in Telugu.

The  English  Idiom means  **trying  to  prevent  the  damage  well  before  but  fail to  do  so  because it  is too  late even  at that  time**. But  the  Telugu  idiom means  trying  to  remedy a  situation    foolishly  after  the  tragedy  happened

Here is  the link

https://www.collinsdictionary.com/amp/english/to-close-the-stable-door-after-the-horse-has-bolted

Comment: "closing the barn door after the horses have escaped", maybe?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [English proverb for when a solution comes too late](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/104948/english-proverb-for-when-a-solution-comes-too-late)

Comment: ... 'closing/shutting the stable door after the horse has bolted'. Given in 2013.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [An English idiom for "solve a problem that has been solved"?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/198530/an-english-idiom-for-solve-a-problem-that-has-been-solved)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Closing the stable door after the horse has bolted

> Trying to prevent or rectify a problem after the damage has already
> been done.

"*If you try to replace the oil filter on the engine now, you're just closing the stable door after the horse has bolted.*"

([Source](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/closing+the+stable+door+after+the+horse+has+bolted))

Comment: @ your  answer  seems  to  be  almost  similar  in  meaningBut  some  sourcses  say  that  some thing  is  done  before  the  damage  but  it  is  too late.The  Telugu  idiom means  doing  something  foolishly after  the  damage

Comment: I've always heard "Shutting the barn door after the cows get out."

Comment: To me, 'shutting the stable door after the horse has bolted' means exactly what you say - trying to remedy a situation after it has happened. By the way, I'm wondering what the leaves are supposed to do to your hands to prevent burning. Is it some special kind of leaf?

Comment: @ Kate Bunting.The  idim is   exactly  the  same  in  the  language .We  have  to  take  its  metophorical  meaning  rather  than its  literal  meaning.Sometimes  people  catch  whatever  is  available  including  leaves  when  they  burnt  themselves.The  leaves  may  not  be  speacial

Comment: @Englishmonger This idiom is identical in meaning to the one you've supplied. It's a remedy that would have saved the damage *had it been previously applied* but it has not. And now you're applying it too late.

Comment: @  Justin.I  have  accepted  your  answer as  it  is  better  of  the two.I  have  upvoted  it  too.

Comment: @Englishmonger - Glad it helped!

Answer (score 3):

Since you don't seem to feel that *closing the barn door after the cows have gone* is equivalent, perhaps a closer idiom would be:

> Rearranging the deck chairs on a sinking ship.

This is trying to fix small cosmetic issues while not noticing the larger overall problem.

For example, creating a new logo for a company when your product is already too obsolete to gain any market share.

Or, doing cosmetic surgery on a patient who is on life support.

A similar idiom would be:

> Too little, too late.